# PHP PDO rowCount not working? I think

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am grabbing the amount of rows in a specific table where the username is already in the database like so:

```
$second_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");    
$second_sql->bindParam(':username', $username);    
$second_sql->execute();

if($second_sql->rowCount() == 1) {
  $db = null;
  header("Location: ../login/");
} else {
  $statement->execute();
  $db = null;
}
```

The problem is it's not working. If you need more of the script just tell me.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It's not grabbing the rowcount.

Comment: you are not fetching anything. you are missing the $result = $second_sql->fetchAll();

Comment: Add `echo $second_sql->rowCount(); exit;` right after the `$second_sql->execute();`. It could be enlightening.

Comment: why not just fetch the data and see if you got a row? i.e. `$user = $second_sql->fetchAll();` `if (!empty($user)) { // process returned data... ` imo, Never use rowCount() with select queries. Just process the data.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases does not report the row count with `PDO->rowCount()` method.

SQLite, for instance.

So don't use `rowCount()`; doing so makes your code less portable.

Instead use the `COUNT(*)` function in your query, and store the result in a variable.

Finally, use that variable to fetch the one and only column (users) using the `fetchColumn()` method.

So you can play with this:

```
try {
    $second_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) from users WHERE username = :username");
    $second_sql->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $second_sql->execute();
    $count = $second_sql->fetchColumn();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Here you can log your error
    // or send an email
    // Never echo this exception on production
    // Only on development fase
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if ($count) {
    $db = null;
    header("Location: ../login/");
} else {
    $statement->execute();
    $db = null;
}
```

Perhaps you wanna test you condition for a single row:

```
if ($count == 1)
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: dude is using mysql and for mysql the rowCount is always available. His problem is **clearly** not with this function but with his DATA: there is simply no row in the database to match the data in the query.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:** I wanted this idea to be as short as 1 line of code:

```
$stmt = $PDO->query( "SELECT * FROM my_table" ); 
$rows = (int) $PDO->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
```

- use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`, then `fetchColumn()`, then class it as an `(int)`

---

**TLDR Version:**

Since PHP8 I have just been using `rowCount()` with impunity, no problems. Then when working on a stack of WP updates *across other peoples servers* I find `rowCount()` **failing to return the proper number of rows**

Of course, I google it and find a decades long debate. I did not like most answers, so I read the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

> According to docs `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` work with
> `rowCount()`, but even on the PHP.NET examples page as far back as 11
> years ago folks have been wrestling with the best/easiest way to just
> count the result.

After testing about 20 answers (stackOverflow to Php.net) the final script [below] worked best to patch 32 WP sites across 20 different servers, 5 hosts and several versions of PHP ranging from 7.4 to 8.1 (GoDaddy, Bluehost, WPengine, InMotion, Amazon AWS Lightsail)

Note that `$opts` turned out to be important (shared, cloud, dedicated)

```
    $db_host = "localhost"; //DB_HOST in WP
    $db_name = "yours";     //DB_NAME in WP
    $db_charset = "utf8mb4";//usually
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$db_charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true, 
        // on/off based on your need: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
        //makes sure addons like counting rows is enabled
    ];
   $PDO = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password, $opt);
   
   // Run the Jewels - do your stuff here
   $stmt = $PDO->query( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' " );

   // one-line count, no shenanagans
   $rows = (int) $PDO->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();

   echo "tell me something useful: $rows";
```